How to make a Discord bot multithreaded for multiple servers?
I have a discord bot (discord.py) with a mafia game algorithm.
Is there any way to make the code multi-threaded, so that several servers can start the game without interfering with other people's sessions?
Like making the code individual for each server.
My guess is to use the threading module. Maybe there are other approaches that will be more effective than threading?

Discord bots using discord.py must be designed asynchronously. Design all of your bot's functions to be asynchronous and you won't need to develop problematic systems with threads.
